# Select values from a vector with respect to time and value in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a  function in R to select some optimal (in terms of distance) points from a vector over time.

Let `x` be a data frame of `x=data.frame(x.val,x.time)`

```
  x.val     x.time
[1,] x1     x.Time1
[2,] x2     x.Time2
[3,] x3     x.Time3
```

and `y` be a data frame of `y=data.frame(y.val,y.time)`

```
  y.val     y.time
[1,] y1     y.Time1
[2,] y2     y.Time2
[3,] y3     y.Time3
[4,] y4     y.Time4
[5,] y5     y.Time5
[6,] y6     y.Time6
[7,] y7     y.Time7
```

Note that `x` and `y` have different lengths `(length(x)=3, length(y)=7)` and we assume that time is a continues measurement here (like in milliseconds).

Having the data structure above, I am looking to write a function to find the closest values in `y` with respect to (1) time and (2) values to `x`.

I should say that it is easy to write the function when `x` contains a single value. In this case, the function seeks the minimum distance on time (simply `abs(y.time-x.time)`)and then finds the minimum distance of `x.value` from the points from the minimum time distance. This is implemented in the code below:

```
set.seed(123456)
    closest.time.value  = function(x, time1, y, time2) {
        # Step 1. minimum distance on time
        tmin  = abs(time2 - time1)
        IndT  = (tmin == min(tmin))
        yy    = y    [IndT]
        ytime = time2[IndT]
        # Step 2. minimum distance of values
        vmin = abs(yy - x)
        VInd  = (vmin == min(vmin))
        ###########
        value = yy   [VInd][1]
        time  = ytime[VInd][1]  ###########

        return(list(
            value = value,
            time = time
        ))
    }
    ##########
    n = 20
    y = round(runif(n), 3)
    time2 = 1:n
    x = runif(1, min(y), max(y))
    time1 = runif(1, 1, n)


    ctv = closest.time.value(
        x = x,
        time1 = time1,
        y = y,
        time2 = time2
    )

    plot(time2, y, main='Blue = the point on y, Green = x')
    points(time1,
                 x,
                 pch = 12,
                 col = 3,
                 lwd = 7)
    points(ctv$time, ctv$value, col = 4, lwd = 4)
    abline(v = ctv$time)
```

One of the challenges that I cannot solve is that the total number of points that are selected from `y` must be equal to the length of `x`. That is no duplicated point is allowed.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Using the @Jrakru56 answer, I have updated the code and solved the problem of duplicates. Here is the final code:

```
closest.time.value  = function(x, time1, y, time2) {
    library(abind)
    x.df = data.frame(x.val = x, x.time = time1)
    y.df = data.frame(y.val = y, y.time = time2)
    output2  = ol = lapply(1:nrow(x.df), function(i) {
        tt <-
            cbind(x.df[i,],
                        lapply(x.df[i,]$x.val, function(v) {
                            diff <- abs(y.df$y.val - v)
                            y.df$dist.V = diff
                            out <- y.df
                        }),
                        ind = i,
                        row.names = NULL)
        tt$dist.T <- abs(tt$x.time - tt$y.time)
        tt$totalD  = tt$dist.V + tt$dist.T
        tt = tt[order(tt$totalD),]
        tt = tt[order(tt$dist.V),]
        tt = tt[order(tt$dist.T),]
    })
    dol = 1
    while (sum(dol) > 0) {
        ol  = lapply(
            X = output2,
            FUN = function(x) {
                if (!is.null(x)  && nrow(x) > 0) {
                    x[1, ]
                } else{
                    NULL
                }
            }
        )
        ol2  = abind(ol, along = 1)
        dol  = duplicated(ol2[, 3:4])
        if (sum(dol)) {
            print(ol2[dol,])
            output2[dol] = lapply(
                output2[dol],
                FUN = function(x) {
                    x[-1, , drop = FALSE]
                }
            )
        }
    }
    ####################
    return(as.data.frame(abind(ol[!unlist(lapply(
        ol,
        FUN = function(x) {
            is.null(x) || length(x) < 1
        }
    ))], along = 1)))
}



##########
# Simulated points
set.seed(123456)
n     = 50 # y length
k     = 9  # x length
deci  = 1  # just to make example fancy!
y     = round(runif(n), deci)
time2 = round(rnorm(n), deci)
x     = round(runif(k, min(y), max(y)), deci)
time1 = round(runif(length(x), min(time2), max(time2)), deci)

ctv = closest.time.value(
    x = x,
    time1 = time1,
    y = y,
    time2 = time2
)

# Plots
plot(time2, y, type = 'p')
points(
    time1,
    x,
    pch = paste(1:length(time1)),
    col = 2,
    cex = 2.5,
    lwd = 7
)
legend(
    'top',
    legend = c('x!', 'y!'),
    fill = c(2, 4),
    horiz = TRUE,
    inset = -.06,
    xpd = TRUE
)

points(
    ctv$y.time,
    ctv$y.val,
    col = 4,
    lwd = 4,
    pch = paste(1:length(ctv$y.time)),
    cex = 2
)
abline(v = ctv$y.time,
             col = 4,
             lty = 3)
abline(v = time1, col = 2, lty = 3)
```

Here is the output of the function:
[image]

Comment: In your example the "dataframes" are matrices! Please use `set.seed(...)` before generating random data.

Comment: There is probably a better way than this but why don't you create a new `data.frame` where each row of x has its corresponding closest y and then from there find the closest y. You obviously know how to solve the single case, so extending it to all the `data.frame` should be straightforward.

Comment: @jogo seed added to the example

Comment: @Jrakru56 Great comment, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is defined at the bottom.

This code compares each value in the `x.df` with the values in the `y.df` create a new `data.frame` for each and then go to find the minimum distance between `values`:

```
lapply(x.df$x.time, function(t) {abs(y.df$y.time - t)})

pos<-unlist(lapply(x.df$x.time, function(t) {which.min(abs(y.df$y.time - t))}))

corresponding.shorted.y <-lapply(x.df$x.time, function(t) {
                                   diff<- abs(y.df$y.time - t);
                                   out <-y.df[diff == min(diff),];
                                   }) 

output<- lapply(1:nrow(x.df), function(i) { 
            tt <- cbind(x.df[i,], corresponding.shorted.y[i], row.names = NULL)
            diff<- abs(tt$y.val - tt$x.val)
            tt[diff == min(diff),]
            })
output
```

**Results:**

```
[[1]]
   x.val x.time y.val y.time
14   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
29   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
31   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
33   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
37   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
38   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
41   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
43   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8
50   0.3    0.8   0.3    0.8

[[2]]
   x.val x.time y.val y.time
5    0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
12   0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
18   0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
21   0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
35   0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
37   0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
39   0.9    0.7   0.9    0.7
```

**Data:**

```r
set.seed(123456)
n = 500
y = round(runif(n), 3)
time2 = 1:n
x = runif(3, min(y), max(y))
time1 = runif(3, 1, n)




y.df <- data.frame("y.val" = y, "y,time" = time2)
x.df <- data.frame("x.val" = x, "x.time" = time1)
```

Comment: I found an example that the function selects the wrong points: set.seed(123456);n = 500;y = round(runif(n), 1);time2 = round(runif(n),1);x = round(runif(2, min(y), max(y)), 1);time1 = round(runif(2, min(time2), max(time2)),1);

Comment: Oh! I did not read your post correct. You want the minimum distance between values. I minimized on time again. Correct ?

Comment: You did quite right. The first step is finding the closest points on time then the closest points on values

Comment: I changed the code to reflect that.  On a different note, if you care about time and value in the same way, you could just calculate the distance between each pair of points and get the minimum too.

Comment: Lol. We will get there eventually. `which.min` grabs the first value it sees. so let's get all the values that match the minimum and we can do the same trick we used for time but the other way around. (see the changes i made)

Comment: Thanks. It seems it works now, however, the problem of duplicates is not solved yet (that is if two points from x are on the same date(time) then the algorithm ends up the same point for y). I also changed the last bit tt[diff == min(diff),] to tt[order(diff),]